# mongodb getting result as sum of values from 2 columns

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "_id" : "357091057690735",
    "lm" : "samsung",
    "ldt" : "S",
    "lmod" : "GT-I8552",
    "lpf" : "A",
    "losv" : "4.1.2",
    "lavn" : "1.0",
    "lc" : "Reliance",
    "flog" : 1470414626.0,
    "llog" : 1475234249.0,
    "ts" : 15.0,
    "tts" : 1869.0,
    "_2016" : [ 
        {
            "tts" : 0.0,
            "tse" : 1.0,
            "_id" : 805.0
        }, 
        {
            "tts" : 46.0,
            "tse" : 1.0,
            "_id" : 811.0
        }, 
        {
            "tts" : 288.0,
            "tse" : 2.0,
            "_id" : 815.0
        }, 
        {
            "tts" : 350.0,
            "tse" : 4.0,
            "_id" : 816.0
        }, 
        {
            "tts" : 18.0,
            "tse" : 1.0,
            "_id" : 819.0
        }, 
        {
            "tts" : 849.0,
            "tse" : 2.0,
            "_id" : 829.0,
            "te" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "tts" : 122.0,
            "tse" : 1.0,
            "_id" : 920.0,
            "tce" : 2.0,
            "te" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "tts" : 27.0,
            "tse" : 1.0,
            "_id" : 928.0,
            "tce" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "tts" : 4.0,
            "tse" : 1.0,
            "_id" : 930.0
        }
    ],
    "_2017" : [ 
        {
            "tts" : 10.0,
            "tse" : 10.0,
            "_id" : 805.0
        }
    ]
 }
```

This is my mongodb document . i want sum(tts) of year 2016 + sum(tts) of year 2017 with condition _2016.tts >= 801 and _2016.tts<=1231) and
_2017.tts >= 801 and 2017.tts<=1231). I have written this query

```
db.coll_users1.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$_2016"},
    {$unwind:"$_2017"},
    {$match:{
        $and:[
                 {$and:[ {'_2016._id': {$gte:801} },{'_2016._id': {$lte:1231}} ] },
                 {$and:[ {'_2017._id': {$gte:801} },{'_2017._id': {$lte:1231}} ] }
             ]
      }
    },
    {$group: {
        _id:'null',
        tts16: {$sum: '$_2016.tts'}, 
        tse16: {$sum: '$_2016.tse'},
        tts17: {$sum: '$_2017.tts'}, 
        tse17: {$sum: '$_2017.tse'}
    } }
])
```

But its giving wrong values for tts_2017

Comment: mongod version?

Comment: It worked for me. what is the other way to achieve it ? Please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you make 2 unwind, and unwind _2017 is second, therefore they appear multiplied by the _2016 size.

These query helps you to divide the value based on 2016 array size, so you will get the correct result:

```
db.coll_users1.aggregate([
    {$project: {_2016:1, _2017:1, count: {$size: "$_2016"} } },
    {$unwind:"$_2016"},
    {$unwind:"$_2017"},

    {$match:{
        $and:[
                 {$and:[ {'_2016._id': {$gte:801} },{'_2016._id': {$lte:1231}} ] },
                 {$and:[ {'_2017._id': {$gte:801} },{'_2017._id': {$lte:1231}} ] }
             ]
      }
    },

    {$group: {
        _id:'null',
        tts16: {$sum: '$_2016.tts'}, 
        tse16: {$sum: '$_2016.tse'},
        tts17: {$sum: '$_2017.tts'}, 
        tse17: {$sum: '$_2017.tse'},
        count_2016_array: {$first: "$count"}
    } },
    { $project : { tts17: { $divide : [ "$tts17", "$count_2016_array" ] }, tts16:1 }}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: its only giving tts17  i also want tts16 means {'_2016._id': {$gte:801} },{'_2016._id': {$lte:1231}}  this conditio result. Cause _2016 & _2017 are 2 different columns

Comment: You can add it in the projection side, I just didnt complete my answer, should be straightforward.

Comment: updated to project tts16. @AJS you get the desired result?

Answer (score -1):

You're unwinding both `$_2016` and `$_2017`, thus you'll end up with 9 * the amount of the same `$_2017` field because of the unwind on `$_2016`

If you just run this part of the aggregation query you'll see what I mean

```
db.coll_users1.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$_2016"},
    {$unwind:"$_2017"},
    {$match:{
        $and:[
                 {$and:[ {'_2016._id': {$gte:801} },{'_2016._id': {$lte:1231}} ] },
                 {$and:[ {'_2017._id': {$gte:801} },{'_2017._id': {$lte:1231}} ] }
             ]
      }
    }
])
```

Comment: You didn't ask for the correct query, so I explained why... the output was showing why it was going wrong... Try reading the whole explanation before commenting _"If you just run this part of the aggregation query you'll see what I mean"_